# Passing pointers as a parameter in C++ rather than using this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Is there a reason or benefit of passing a pointer to class/object rather than using the "this" pointer to the current address object to access member variables? Is this one that boils down to personal preference (to me the second version seems a bit redundant) but maybe its for code re-usability?

```
class Box
{
   public:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box

      double getVolume(Box *box);
};

double Box::getVolume(void)
{
    return length * breadth * height;
}
```

VS

```
double Box::getVolume(Box *box)
{
    return this->length * this->breadth * this->height;
}
```

Comment: It lets you pass a pointer to *a different instance*.

Comment: Yes I see that, but getVolume is a member of the class. Why not use the dot operator for different instances of the class say `Box b1, b2; b1.getVolume(); b2.getVolume();`

Comment: `Foo a, b; a.do_something(&b);`

Comment: In the second example you're mixing properties from the current object with properties from the argument object. Is that intentional.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh yea DUH! Never crossed my mind to do something like that.

Comment: Note that if you changed every `this` to `box` in the second example, `this` wouldn't even be used, which means there's no point having it as a non-static member function. But then you're basically just recreating the concept of member functions which have an implicit `this` parameter.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf My understanding of what is happening there with the second one is if for example you passed in a pointer to a box object say Box b1 that it would be accessing the member variables for b1. So say Box *foo = &b1; getVolume(Box *foo); and the return would be the volume of the b1 box. Is that not correct?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Sorry those are all supposed to be "this->" the first  "box->" was a mistake.

Comment: @BobR: it's using the length of the current object and the breadth and height of the argument object.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry those are all supposed to be "this->" the first "box->" was a mistake.

Comment: @Bob In that case the `box` parameter is completely unused and is pointless.

Comment: this->length is the same as length.  Perhaps it was intended to be a static function, in which case I'd agree with Joseph -- there's no point. It's an instance specific method and you have an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to get straight: a non-static member function is essentially just like any other function, but has an implicit parameter called `this` which is a pointer to the object that the member function was called on. That is, calling `foo.bar()` can be thought of as similar to calling `bar(&foo)`, where the first parameter is called `this`.

Now, in your first case, if you do `some_box.getVolume()`, it will calculate the volume of `some_box`, since a pointer to `some_box` is passed as `this`.

In your second case, you have exactly the same function, but you have introduced an unused parameter `box`. Since you're not using it, it's completely pointless. It would mean that you would have to pass a pointer to a `box` every time you called `getVolume`, yet that pointer wouldn't be used at all. That is, you'd have to call either `some_box.getVolume(&some_box)` or `some_box.getVolume(&another_box)`.

Now you *could* change every `this` inside the second function to `box` and then you would be working out the volume of the `box` that was passed via the pointer parameter. That is, `some_box.getVolume(&another_box)` would give you the volume of `another_box`. But now the implicit `this` parameter is unused and pointless! Now you might as well make it either a static member function or just a non-member function.

If you were to do this, you're basically just mimicking the idea of member functions - instead of an implicit `this` parameter, you have an explicit `box` parameter. What's the point? The language feature of member functions is a neater way of doing this.

Comment: Ok, I see whats going on here. &another_box is just "dead code" that's hopefully getting optimized out by the compiler as it does nothing. I'm not going to assume to know what the original author was thinking. Perhaps the code was non-member functions made into members of the class. I was confused by it.The box class was just an  example. Doesn't help I couldn't ask it right and not make mistakes when I input it :P

Answer (score 0):

You want const so that you can getVolume on const references and pointers.

```
double Box::getVolume() const
```

The second option is bad (misleading) code.  The argument is not used, but anyone using the class would expect it to be used for something.